# bash replace string based on array lookup value

Tags: bash

**tldr** In bash, given a stream of input, how to replace some known string with the value of an array lookup?

Given code

```sh
declare -Ag mapping=()
# in the real case, the array `mapping` is determined at runtime
mapping["1"]="one"
mapping["2"]="two"
mapping["55"]="fifty-five"

# the structure of the input is known but the values are determined at runtime
echo "1 foo
2 bar
55 baz" | magic_mapper
```

I want `magic_mapper` to print

```
1 foo one
2 bar two
55 baz fifty-five
```

Again, the particular values in `mapping`, and stream of input to `magic_mapper` is not known ahead of time.  The *structure* of input to `magic_mapper` is known.

What should `magic_mapper` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do with a `while` loop over `read`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

magic_mapper() {
    while read -r name val; do
        echo "$name $val ${mapping[$name]}"
    done
}

declare -Ag mapping=()
# in the real case, the array `mapping` is determined at runtime
mapping["1"]="one"
mapping["2"]="two"
mapping["55"]="fifty-five"

# the structure of the input is known but the values are determined at runtime
echo "1 foo
2 bar
55 baz" | magic_mapper
```

Comment: nice @Shawn ! yeah, I came up with something very similar.  Thanks for helping me brainstorm. :-)